# Ordering Custom Properties

Tags: 2013, web-part, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a Client WebPart, and while doing some simple debugging against office 365, i noticed that no matter how i structured the custom properties in the query string they were always laid out in the order of the Edit Properties panel.

### Ideal Layout:

- SQL Connection

  1. Server
  2. Database
- SQL Query

  1. Type
  2. Statement

### Current QueryString

`<Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/ClientSQLTextBox.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;property2=_sql_&amp;SqlType=_type_&amp;Database=_db_&amp;Server=_instance_" />`

### Current Layout

[image]

### Question

How do i get the Order of the Properties to be in contextual order.  Eventually, the SQL Connection group will be expanded to more properties, as well as the SQL Query.

1. How do i order the Properties.
2. Is there a way of make certain properties conditionally visible based on another properties selection?

#### Appended Question (Edit 2014-03-19)

Is there a way of creating or managing the Edit Panel for properties?

Ideally i would append or insert my sections into the existing Edit Panel, not necessarily override.

Comment: From testing this is seriously frustrating.  The Properties are in Alphabetic order of the description not the name or the order in which they show in the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well seems when doing Client WebParts (uses Javascript, instead of CodeBehind logic).  The control of the Edit Properties, is out of your control.

If those of you that find this article, make sure to note that it might be better for you to simply put your Property customization within the webpart itself, refer to [Marc D Anderson's Blog Post](http://sympmarc.com/2013/05/03/determine-if-a-sharepoint-publishing-page-is-in-design-mode-edit-mode-with-script/) to read on how to do it Client Side.  And for those of us doing native .Net WebParts, a good read is on [My Step Stones](http://mystepstones.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/detecting-the-current-mode-displayedit/).

Great thing about Native WebParts, is that the order in which you list them in the class, if you use the Attribute method of adding to the EditPanel, is the order in which they seem to show up for me.

Catch in either of the above situations, is that the properties will always be at the bottom of the Sets of Properties.  In order to get around this, you will need to create your own custom EditPanel handler (i use handler loosely to describe the override behavior).

#### Good Reads on the EditToolPart

1. [Nothing But SharePoint](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-Creating-a-Custom-ToolPart-for-a-Custom-Web-Part.aspx)
2. [Neal Mukundan](http://sptechbytes.blogspot.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2010-configurable-web-part.html)